# Probability proof question (probability theory).

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $A^C$ and $B^C$ are the events complementary to $A$ and $B$, and
$p(A|B) > p(A)$ and $p(B^C) > 0$, prove that  $p(A^C|B^C) > p(A^C)$.

Been trying to get my head around this but kind of stuck and any help would be much appreciated.

I know that $p(A|B)=p(A~and~B)/p(B)$, $p(A^C)= 1 - p(A)$... therefore $p(A)= 1- p(A^C)$... I was just subbing these in and trying to re arrange to find the required result but didnt get far and i'm in need of some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$p(A|B)>p(A)$$
$$p(A \cap B)>p(A)p(B)$$
$$p(A^C \cap B^C)=1-p(A)-p(B)+p(A \cup B)$$
$$p(A^C \cap B^C)>1-p(A)-p(B)+p(A)p(B)$$
$$p(A^C \cap B^C)>(1-p(A))(1-p(B))$$
$$p(A^C \cap B^C)>p(A^C)p(B^C)$$
$$p(A^C|B^C)>p(A^C)$$

assuming $0<p(A),p(B)<1$ so i don't divide or multiply by zero

Comment: Great answer! +1